# Which ordinal is larger, the supremum of ordinals writable by iterated Infinite Time Turing Machines or the smallest $\Sigma_2^1$-reﬂecting ordinal?

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, computability-theory, ordinal-numbers

The ordinal $\tau_1$ corresponds to $\lambda^{\textit{it}}$ (the supremum of all ordinals writable by *iterated ITTMs*) — see Deﬁnition 3.1 in the paper [“ITTMs with Feedback” [Robert S. Lubarsky]](https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/ITTMs-with-Feedback-Lubarsky/980d560b8f991113f5d132b4d161a78e712a067c). According to Theorem 3.4 in the paper, the ordinal $\zeta^{\textit{it}}$ (the supremum of the ordinals eventually writable by *iterated ITTMs*) is the least $\kappa$ which is $\kappa$-extendible, and $\lambda^{\textit{it}}$ is the smallest $\Sigma_1$ substructure of $\zeta^{\textit{it}}$.

The ordinal $\tau_2$ corresponds to #2.25 in “A zoo of ordinals” [David A. Madore]. It is defined as the smallest $\sigma$ such that $L_{\sigma} \preceq_1 L$, or equivalently $L_{\sigma} \preceq_1 L_{\omega_1}$. This is also the smallest $\Sigma_2^1$-reﬂecting ordinal.

Which ordinal is larger, $\tau_1$ or $\tau_2$?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The quickest answer is to say $\zeta^{it}$ is the smaller because it can be computed inside any transitive $ZF^-$ model; if $L_\gamma$ is the least such model, then $\gamma < \sigma$ - the latter ordinal also being the smallest $\Sigma^1_2$-reflecting ordinal. (Indeed it can be computed inside the least $L_\tau$ where $\tau$ is $\Sigma_2$-non-projectible. Such a $\tau$ is a $\tau$-extendible limit of $\kappa$-extendibles etc. $
\Pi^1_3$-$CA$ is enough to prove the existence of the ordinal $\zeta
^{it}$. So $ZF^-$ was overkill.) So $\tau_1$ is less than $\tau_2$ in the nomenclature of the question.

Comment: It seems that this answer, in its current form, implies that the supremum of all ordinals writable by iterated ITTMs is less than the smallest $\Sigma_2^1$-reﬂecting ordinal, but I think that an explicit statement is needed.

Comment: Sorry, it was indeed unclear.

Comment: Sorry to comment on an old post and sorry if I am not understanding you correctly, but $\Pi^1_3-CA$ is an arithmetical theory and thus it can't talk about ordinals, much less prove the existence of large unrecursive ones. Do you mean some weakened fragment of ZF that is equiconsistent with $\Pi^1_3-CA$? Or do you mean that the minimal model height of $\Pi^1_3-CA$ is more than $\zeta$?

Comment: @Boris: to say "$\Pi^1_3$-$CA$  can talk about ordinals" is just a loose way of stating that it can prove the existence of sets of natural numbers that code well orderings of those order types. And 'yes' to the last question.